# python way of left_value = (condition) ? val_a : val_b

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there something similar in python we do this

```
left = (condition) ? val_a : val_b
```

It seems not working in python.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

```py
left = val_a if condition else val_b
```